# Convert output of a command or script in a custom single line

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

[image: output image]
Above hyperlink is the output image.

Hi All,

I want to convert the whole output in a single line result in powershell.Below is my code,

```
$containername = "testoutput" 

$storageAccKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName 
$rgname -AccountName $storageAccountName)[0].value 

$storagecontext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccKey 

New-AzStorageContainer -Name $containername -Context $storagecontext -Permission Off 

Write-Output "Container $($containername) created"
```

Comment: What is the command you have used?

Comment: $containername = "testoutput" 
$storageAccKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $rgname -AccountName $storageAccountName)[0].value
$storagecontext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccKey
New-AzStorageContainer -Name $containername -Context $storagecontext -Permission Off
Write-Output "Container $($containername) created"

Comment: Perhaps it's better that you edit your question and put your code there as comments doesn't support line breaks.

Comment: AFAIK, we cannot combine final output with a string value. because if you want to call the string value, in the same output line we need a positional parameter to call the string value in the same line  [image1](https://i.imgur.com/FCw2yEU.png) [image2](https://i.imgur.com/92yB9Ux.png)

Comment: Its better if you post your required output. Its hard to assume and answer.

Comment: if you look at the screenshot attached, there is a detailed output. I want my output like
"container xyz created" or something one liner rather getting the complete output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is what you're looking for:

```
$containername = "testoutput"
$storageAccountName = "teststorage001"

$storageAccKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $rgname -AccountName $storageAccountName)[0].value 

$storagecontext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccKey 

$result = New-AzStorageContainer -Name $containername -Context $storagecontext -Permission Off 

Write-Host "Container $($containername) created in Storage Account-"$($result.Name)",PublicAccess-"$($result.PublicAccess)",LastModified-"$($result.LastModified)""
```

Either Write-Host or Write-Output can be used. The multiple lines you're seeing is the result of New-AzStorageContainer. Now, I have assigned it to a variable called $result and used in Write-Output.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve your requirement is to use if-else condition and check `New-AzStorageContainer -Name $containername -Context $storagecontext -Permission Off` doesn't result null. Below is the complete code that worked for me.

```
$rgname = "<YOUR_RESOURCE_GROUP>"
$containername = "<YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME>" 
$storageAccountName = "<YOUR_STORAGE_ACCOUNT>"

$storageAccKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $rgname -AccountName $storageAccountName)[0].value 

$storagecontext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccKey 

if((New-AzStorageContainer -Name $containername -Context $storagecontext -Permission Off) -ne $null){
    Write-Output "Container $($containername) created"
}else{
    Write-Output "Container $($containername) Not created"
}
```

*RESULTS:*

[image]